# code syntax hightlight changes for C make code harder to read

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know whether it was today, or in the last few days, but it looks like the C code syntax highlighting changed. What really pops out to me is the comment color `#define` syntax highlight, green string literal highlight and blue highlight only for variables that begin with upper-case, purple'ish keywords, among other things.

I don't know what the colors were before, but I recall them being "comfortable", with `#define`'s all of similar color, variable names all being the same, and the sting literals (*format-strings*, etc.) not jumping off the page.

for example:

[image]

(original from: [**Reading 3 strings from a text file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902460/reading-3-strings-from-a-text-file/36903163#36903163))

I could just be getting senile, but I'm interested if anyone else has noticed the changes and what your thoughts are on it? If there are any options to tweak the C-highlight, it would be nice to see something without different colors for variable names, etc.. If it can't be changed, that's fine, it just looks a little wonky.

---

**Edit - If fixing C# will fix C, then this is a Duplicate**

I reviewed the question that is suggested as the reason this question should be marked as a duplicate. If fixing the `C#` syntax will also fix `C` syntax, then yes, this is a duplicate. However, if the languages are not tied together (as they are not in GNU Highlight, etc.), then this isn't a duplicate and we need to make sure `C` is fixed along with the other question about `C#`. You guys on metasSO know better than I, so I'll leave that to your decision. (and yes, if the answer is to revert *All* syntax highlighting -- then of course this is covered there).

Comment: Why on earth are `New` and `NameLast` in this C code getting highlighted like type names when they're ordinary variables? This is utterly broken.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I think the old syntax highlighting used to highlight them as well. The highlighting comes because they start with an uppercase letter, but I agree. They are no different from ordinary variables.